# Repeating characters in a word are being suppressed by character recognition models

Tags: deep-learning, ocr, text-recognition, paddleocr, openmmlab

I have trained a **SATRN_small** model on a custom dataset using **MMOCR** framework for character recognition as well as a **SVRT_LCNet** model using **PaddleOCR**.

The loss function used in MMOCR is ***CrossEntropyLoss***, and the loss function used by PaddleOCR is a combination of ***CTC*** loss and ***SAR*** loss.

The repeating characters in a word are being suppressed by both models. for e.g, 40799932 is predicted as 4079932.

What is the reason for this problem? Is there any solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.